# pending intent broadcast uniquely

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

when I broadcast pending intent and provide my data by `putExtra()` , I get these intents in receiver with same data and this equal the 1st created Pending intent 
. code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    mSendIntent=new  Intent("CTS_SMS_SEND_ACTION");
    mSendIntent.putExtra("key",i):
    sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smscontext, 0, mSendIntent,
            0));
}
```

I try to get my result with adding some flag to `getBroadcast` method but not successful ,any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a unique `PendingIntent` each time you call `getBroadcast()`, you need to provide either a unique Intent action or a unique request code. In your example it may be easiest to provide a unique request code. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    mSendIntent=new Intent("CTS_SMS_SEND_ACTION");
    mSendIntent.putExtra("key", i):
    sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(smscontext, i, mSendIntent, 0));
}
```

I've used `i` as the `requestCode` parameter. However, `i` may not be unique enough (I don't know the rest of your code). You may need to add the date or some other value to make it unique.